# Powershell - Read Text File and Create a New File based on each line of the text file

Tags: command-line, powershell

I am trying to create a new filename based upon the content of an existing text file. For example,

```
FileNameList.txt
===============
Places to Visit
Things to Take
Things to do in Home Before Leaving
# Line with # at the beginning, skip
```

I would like to convert this file lines into its own file names using **PowerShell**. The Folder name does not matter. it can be in the existing folder.

Output will be:

```
Places to Visit.txt
Things to Take.txt 
Things to do in Home Before Leaving.txt
```

Notice, that

1. There could be spaces or _ or comma or . in the line.
2. If the filename already exists, it should overwrite the file.
3. Adding one more request, any line starting with # symbol should be skipped.

Things I tried: I tried to use CSV file and try to use Import-Csv, but did not go very far.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use `$filenames = Get-Content FileNameList.txt` to get the contents of your file into an array and then process from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following cmdlets:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\yourfile.txt" | foreach { if(!$_.StartsWith("#")){ New-Item "$_.txt" -Force }}

...

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          24/08/2023    19:43              0 Places to Visit.txt
-a---          24/08/2023    19:43              0 Things to Take.txt
-a---          24/08/2023    19:43              0 Things to do in Home Before Leaving.txt
```

**Explanation:** Gets the file's content. Checks each line. If it doesn't start with `#`, it creates a new file. The `-Force` parameter allows to overwrite existing file if they already exist.

Comment: Great. This works perfectly. Can I save this as ps1 file and run that whenever I need to?

Comment: @NotepadPlusPlusPRO I don't see what stops you from doing it.